# How to create a query of array of json objects with retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to generate the following query with retrofit2

```
s=[{"uuid":"f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e","major":29551,"minor":30826}]
```

I tried several ways including:

```
@Query("s[uuid]") String uuid,
@Query("s[major]") int major,
@Query("s[minor]") int minor
```

But i am unable to create the query correctly using retrofit2, what is the correct way to generate the query i want?

Comment: I have done the required calling for you please check it@Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query parameter is the `s`, so you need something like:

```
@Query("s") MyParamType s
```

A simple solution would be declaring a class (e.g. `MyParamType`) with the attributes (`uuid`, `major`, `minor`) and override the `toString()` method to return the desired format.

**Example:**

```
public String toString() {
  return String.format("[{\"uuid\":\"%s\",\"major\":%d,\"minor\":%d}]", this.uudi, this.major, this.minor);
}
```

Comment: Hi there thank you for your suggestion but the final url doesn't have the string returned from MyParamType logcat shows it correctly but it doesnt get passed to http request correctly seems some escape char is missing or something

Comment: I got it working thanks I am accepting your answer :)

Comment: @Steve  I am glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step Steve.First Convert your JSON array to Pojo.I have done this for you check this:

```
public class BeaconPojo {







        @SerializedName("uuid")
        @Expose
        private String uuid;
        @SerializedName("major")
        @Expose
        private Integer major;
        @SerializedName("minor")
        @Expose
        private Integer minor;

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The uuid
         */
        public String getUuid() {
            return uuid;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param uuid
         * The uuid
         */
        public void setUuid(String uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The major
         */
        public Integer getMajor() {
            return major;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param major
         * The major
         */
        public void setMajor(Integer major) {
            this.major = major;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The minor
         */
        public Integer getMinor() {
            return minor;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param minor
         * The minor
         */
        public void setMinor(Integer minor) {
            this.minor = minor;
        }

    }
```

Then create an interface like this:

```
public class EndPointInterface {
    @GET("getBecon")
    Call<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>> getBeacons();
}
```

After that Create an Utilility class:

public class ApiUtil {

```
 public static final boolean isEnableLogging = true;


    public static Retrofit getPetListInstance(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if(isEnableLogging)
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        else
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constant.base_url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

    }





}
```

Then when you are calling the webservice try this:

```
ApiEndInterface service = 

    ApiUtil.getPetListInstance().create(ApiEndInterface.class);
            Call<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>> call = service.getPets();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>> call, Response<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<BeaconPojo>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi @CrazyAndroid, thanks for trying to help but if i am not mistaken you posted a solution for how to convert the received json from webservice to pojo. This is not what i want i want to the build an url GET with the following s=[{"uuid":"f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e","major":29551,"minor":30826}] as an query parameter!

Comment: Yes for the query parameter I have provided the EndPointInterface.Please go through it  thoroughly@Stev